# WordPress Unbounce Plugin HTTPS not working

Tags: plugins, ssl

Greatings,

I'v recently start working with Unbounce, a landing page page tool and set it to work on my wordpress site. But i'm facing an issue.

The landing page perfectly work in `http://url.com/landingpage` but not in `https://url.com/landingpage` where the page is literally EMPTY. Nothing on the page, and connection error.

I have no clue how can i make the page work using HTTPS since my wordpress site is actually using it without any problem.

Anyone can maybe help me to understand and fix my problem?

Thanks in advence.

Comment: You should start by asking Unbounce for support, especially if you're a paying customer. They'll know how the plugin works best.

Comment: I'd also check your server error log for errors if you haven't already - there might be something in there. Apart from that it looks like the actual landing pages are configured on Unbounce's servers, so maybe there's an URL in your config there that is HTTP only not HTTPS? You can probably debug what their plugin is doing too, e.g. try and trace out any requests it makes to its home server, but that's going to be more work.

Comment: Turns out there's built-in debug logging. Add `define( 'UB_ENABLE_LOCAL_LOGGING', true );` to your wp-config. I'd focus on debugging the `add_action('init', function () {` block in Unbounce-Page.php as that looks like the relevant logic.